# How to select a Screen area from Video?

Tags: video, video-capture, video-processing, video-editing

Which software is used to select some screen portion of a video?

For example I want to remove the footer of a video.

[image]

In the above picture I want to remove the selected portions in the rectangle.

Kindly suggest me some software to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure on this but you might be able to use Microsoft Expression Encoder 4.
It also includes supposedly the best Screen Recorder program you can get, so if you can't use the main piece of software you could always use that by playing the video in Media Player and recording the desired area of the screen. I know it's not exactly designed for what you want to do, but it would theoretically work. Hope this helps :)